# Does randomIO (from System.Random) ever produce 0?

Tags: haskell, random

I understand that `randomIO::IO Float` produces uniformly distributed `Float` numbers, but my question is in what range? Is it `[0,1]`, `(0,1)` or anything in between (`[0,1)` or `(0,1]`)?

I couldn't find anything about it on [hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html), and the referenced paper is behind a paywall.

The reason I'm asking is because you might want to transform the random number, and if you want to evaluate `1/myRandomNumber` it would be helpful to know whether you will ever run into `Infinity` or not.

```hs
import System.Random
main=(randomIO::IO Float)>>=print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRCG4srgkNVcvKDEvJT@XKzcxM89WowjM8fS3svL0V3DLyU8s0bSzsy0oyswr@f8fAA)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer**: the range is **[0, 1)**.

Yes. The implementation of `Random` for a `Float` is [[source]](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/src/System-Random.html):

```
instance Random Float where
  randomR = randomRFloating
  random rng = 
    -- TODO: Faster to just use 'next' IF it generates enough bits of randomness.   
    case random rng of 
      (x,rng') -> 
          -- We use 24 bits of randomness corresponding to the 24 bit significand:
          ((fromIntegral (mask24 .&. (x::Int32)) :: Float) 
       /  fromIntegral twoto24, rng')
     -- Note, encodeFloat is another option, but I'm not seeing slightly
     --  worse performance with the following [2011.06.25]:
--         (encodeFloat rand (-24), rng')
   where
     mask24 = twoto24 - 1
     twoto24 = (2::Int32) ^ (24::Int32)
```

It uses a random 32-bit integer `x` (where zero is a possible value), it masks out the first 8 bits, and divides that value by *2<sup>24</sup>*. As a result the range is 0 (included) to 1 (excluded). The largest value it can represent is `0.999999940395`.

The reason it works that way is because a `Float` has a 24-bit mantisse (as well as 7-bit exponent and a sign bit). By transforming it in that range, we guarantee that every `Float` value is equally probable: the last 24 bits are first copied into the mantisse of the `Float`, then the float is normalized, and the exponent altered such that the values are in the [0, 1) range.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I didn't even know you could access the source!